# Knockout.js - javascript function on data-bind

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

Is there a way i can call JavaScript function on data-bind like this:

```
<span id="lblSomePropVal" data-bind="text: MySomeFunction(SomeProperty())" ></span>
```

What i am trying to do is call MySomeFunction with the value of SomeProperty of my viewmodel. My SomeFunction will return some text based on value passed and that will be displayed in the span lblSomePropVal.

I tried it the way i have written in the example but it throws binding error.

Am i missing something here or is there any other way of doing this?

This is the error i am getting:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: [object Error];
Bindings value: text: MySomeFunction(SomeProperty())
```

Comment: Try out `data-bind="text: MySomeFunction.bind(SomeProperty())"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use arbitrary JavaScript expressions for bindings, but keep in mind that they are evaluated in the viewmodel's context, so all functions in the expression have to be properties of viewmodel. In your case, *MySomeFunction* has to be a property of your viewmodel. If you create your viewmodel using mapping plugin, you can attach additional functions to the viewmodel like this:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d)
viewModel.MySomeFunction = function(...){...};
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I keep getting `MySomeFunction` is undefined?

Comment: I also keep getting "is undefined" when using this method.

Comment: got to fully qualify it otherwise it can't be seen... assuming its within a library or module

Comment: I also had trouble getting this to work then I remembered about binding context.  I was in a foreach binding, therefore to get to the function on the view model I had to use $root.functionName rather than just functionName

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem trying to calculate table cell entries.  What worked for me was including 'MySomeFunction' in my data model, and then data-binding my table cells as:

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.MySomeFunction(SomeProperty)"></td>
```

Comment: And if you're still having trouble, try `<td data-bind="text: console.log($root)"></td>` to make sure $root has the properties you're expecting.

Answer (score 5):

Well I am just going through the tutorial myself but I thought you had to set up a property and use ko.computed to give it its value (from the tutorial):

```
function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){ 
  return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); 
  },this);
}
```

Then you can have:

```
Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong>
```

Comment: I know this can be done but i was wondering if i can call a JS function in the binding attribute that way i dont have to write lots of JS code to manipulate every single property

Comment: Peter is right here.  You can just build your function inside your viewmodel and it will work.  For example, if MySomeFunction was inside AppViewModel above, you could call it just fine.  Additionally, you can use basic javascript stuff like `.toUpperCase()` inside the data-bind

Comment: I think this is not working because my function is outside the viewmodel. I am using knockout mapper to declare my viewmodel (var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d);). How do i attach a function to my viewmodel below that?

Comment: you can call another function outside the view model just use the function name like : this.fullname = ko.computed(hello,this); and if you have a function named hello elsewhere it will work. I am not sure about it taking a parameter though.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this by using the context. If you need the whole code I can send it to you.

```
<h2 class="text" data-bind="html: currentProgram($context)"></h2>

function currentProgram(context){
  var title = '<font size="1">' + context.$data.name + '</font>';
  return title;
}
```

You will also need to set this

```
       $.ajaxSetup({
          async: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="font-size:18px;float:left;width:95%" data-bind="html: trimString(AccountName,25)"></div>

function trimString(value, maxLen) {

    //Return undefined, and short strings
    if (value === undefined) return undefined;
    if (value.length < maxLen) return value;

    return value.substring(0, (maxLen - 1));    
}
```