# Knockout use function with mapping plugin and data binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have almost exactly the same question as [Knockout.js - javascript function on data-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536856/knockout-js-javascript-function-on-data-bind)
but I use the mapping plugin.

This is my viewmodel and mapping:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
viewModel.FromUnixTs = function (uts) {
    var date = new Date(uts * 1000);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and this is my html binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root">
    <tr class="gv">
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: FromUnixTs(date_time())"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

also tried:

- `<td data-bind="text: FromUnixTs(date_time)"></td>`
- `<td data-bind="text: $root.FromUnixTs(date_time())"></td>`
- `<td data-bind="text: $root.FromUnixTs(date_time)"></td>`
- `<td data-bind="text: date_time"></td>` works but not formatted like a datetime

and

- `viewModel.prototype.FromUnixTs = function (uts) {`

the error I keep getting is: `FromUnixTs is not defined` or not found. Besides a solution, I would also like a bit more context for my mistake. What I did wrong and why etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues. Here's my 2 cts.

1. Not a biggie, but it's clearer if you could structure your data in a way that the top-level isn't the array itself, but an object with that array, e.g. `{ items: [/* original data here*/] }`.
2. With the MVVM pattern it's best not to put logic in your view, and `text: FromUnixTs(date_time())` borders that. Instead, put all that logic on your view model and just have a `text: UnixTx` binding. This also works around the problematic code in your question surrounding the `prototype` stuff.
3. If you want to augment view models created with the mapping plugin, you can do so by creating mapping options that allow you to tweak the model upon creation.
4. Finally, a problem that prevents others from helping you: your question contains irrelevant code (the jQuery ajax stuff) making it harder to understand things, and the examples are incomplete and invalid snippets (unclosed tags, etc). In addition, you ask many questions in one, creating a very large question (almost a review request) which SO users tend to shy away from.

If I put all this together (at least 1-3), then I'd suggest a different approach like the following. Update your View to this:

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr class="gv">
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: unixTs"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No logic there.

Then, assuming the following data:

```
var data = {
    items: [{id: 1, number:  42, date_time: 1375948769449},
            {id: 2, number: 106, date_time: 1375948769349}]
};
```

I'd construct the view model using the mapping plugin like this:

```
var mapping = {
    'items': {
        create: function (item) {
            return new ItemViewModel(item.data);
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, {});
```

This uses an `ItemViewModel` constructor function that augments the mapped VM with the `unixTs` observable:

```
var ItemViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    this.unixTs = ko.computed(function () {
        var date = new Date(self.date_time());
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    });
};
```

You can see all this at work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMBzB/). Hope this helps.

---

If you can't change the structure of the data from the server, you can still use the augmented view model version. With a few changes:

```
// Data not augmented, just the raw array OP gets from the service
var data = [{id: 1,number: 42,date_time: 1375948769449},
            {id: 2,number: 106,date_time: 1375948769349}];

// Augment the data into an object to make a clearer view model:
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({items: data}, mapping, {});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58cn6/).

Comment: Thanks, about nr4. I added the jQuery part, just in case it had something to do with global variables and not being able to reach it or something. I have never created a viewmodel before in a success function of ajax. And the unclosed html was just trying to keep it readable. But I can definitely work with this answer. Is it by the way true that the first option of Anders would work for me?

Comment: And about number one: I cannot change the data I receive from the server. So I cannot wrap it in an object. But I guess that the KO mapping plugin takes this var mapping and handles that part. But somehow I get a `items is not defined`

Comment: I've added a footnote for the case where you can't change the result from the server.

Comment: If you still are having trouble I suggest you boil it down to the [smallest possible piece of code](http://sscce.org) and ask a new question about *just* that issue. This is probably the easiest way to get good responses from SO users. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cant use prototype on a object instance like that, adding the function directly to the reference works

http://jsfiddle.net/DGzrR/

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
vm.foo = function() {
    console.log("foo");
};
```

But not good practice, instead do
http://jsfiddle.net/DGzrR/1/

```
MyViewModel = function(data) {
    this.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
}

MyViewModel.prototype = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log("foo");
        console.log(this.items().length);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for your reply, but I have tested your first method. It did not work and why is it a bad practise?

Comment: Even with `viewModel.FromUnixTs = function () {` and `<td data-bind="text: FromUnixTs()"></td>` I get `FromUnixTs is not defined`